# How to change the whole program’s skin style in Android?

Tags: android

How to change the whole program’s Skin style?

It can use the specialized apk to implement sharing. But I do not know how to directly use the apk element in the current program.

Could you give me some advice？ Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

You can define a style that has one of Android theme styles as parent:

```
<style name="main_style" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00000000</item>
    <!-- any other customizations -->
</style>
```

and then, in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, apply it the following way

to the activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity1"
    android:theme="@style/main_style"/>

<activity
    android:name=".Activity2"
    android:theme="@style/main_style"/>
```

or to your whole application:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/main_style">
```

There's no need to define your own theme, you can also use one of stock Android themes:

```
<application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define style for your app.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html